# Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory - Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, master-pages

I had a website created using Asp.Net framework 3.5 and And now I'm upgrading it to Visualstudio 2015 (framework 4.6)..

When click on any link it throws an error- Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

```
 string mslinepath = ResolveUrl("~/" + dt_submenu.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString().Trim());
            string pagenamesub = mslinepath + "?Session=" + dt_submenu.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString().Trim(); //"Framework.aspx?name=" +
            // nav.InnerHtml += "<li> <a href=\"" + pagenamesub + "\">" + UppercaseFirstEach(dt_submenu.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()) + "</a> ";
            str += "<li> <a href=\"" + pagenamesub + "\">" + UppercaseFirstEach(dt_submenu.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()) + "</a> ";
            submenu(dt_submenu.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim());
            //  nav.InnerHtml += "</li>";
```

If anyone knows the solution please let me know.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's the provided link which causes error? How this link looks like in browser? The error states link uses double dot shortcut to go beyond root folder.

Comment: in browser - http://localhost:1502/(S(pg51xdsdttccmbhmj1y2q3qa))/Settings_Spz/Letter_Of_Credit_List.aspx?Session=LC001

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the answer was actually quite simple:

Open your master page and review all your include files, css, js, etc..

```
Replace: 

href="../" 

with 

href="/"
```

In other words, the master page must use absolute path and not relative.